# PHP PDO Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined

Tags: php, pdo

This is my code :

It gives no error when i change the array to index type instead of associative.
But the moment i change it back to associative it starts giving error.
Any help on this ?

```
$dbh=new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=sj_db", 'root', '');

$entryData = array(
    "Team Name"=>$_POST['name']
  , "Won"=>$_POST['w']
  , "Lost"=>$_POST['l']
  , "Draw"=>$_POST['d']
  , "Points"=>$_POST['p']
  );


$sql="INSERT INTO fb (`Team Name`, Won, Lost, Draw, Points) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
$sth=$dbh->prepare($sql);
//$sth->execute($entryData[`Team Name`],$entryData['Won'],$entryData['Lost'],$entryData['Draw']
//  ,$entryData['Points']);
$sth->execute($entryData);

//$sth->closeCursor();
```

Comment: Your `$entryData` associative array has 10 items in it, five values and five keys. You need to have just the values in there.

Comment: But i needed the keys for further uses.
Any way to do that ?

Comment: -1 for just stating "it starts giving error" but not posting the error itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Placeholders in your query are positional (?) ones.
Either change them to named (`:name`)
or pass `array_values($entryData)` into execute

Though you have to remove a space from `Team Name` key in order to use named placeholders

Comment: And about the space thing.. Can't i use ` instead of ' for Team Name...wudnt that do ?

Comment: Neither ` nor ' symbol has nothing to do with **placeholders**, mind you. That's why you've been told to remove a space - that's the only way

Comment: Then it means there's no way to use placeholders for the columns having a space in their name ?

Comment: Add to your question what have you tried. We cannot know it just from your words "i did try"

Comment: Who said it's impossible? **remove a space from the key name** as you have been told

Comment: hey both the methods worked..
Thanks a lot..!!
and sorry for my misbehaving..hope u didnt mind that :)

Comment: Oh no, I never mind. An there was no misbehaving from you at all.